# Mysqli failing to insert boolean in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to INSERT a new row into my db via php7.

Mysqli is throwing the error

```
Column 'newsletter' cannot be null
```

The newsletter column in the database is a tinyint(1)

[image: The database structure]

Here is the code:

```
public function Add_User(array $data) {

    if( !isset($data['name']) || !isset($data['email']) || !isset($data['newsletter']) )

            $optin = ( $data['newsletter'] === 'on' ) ? 1 : 0;
            $country_code = $this->Get_Country_Code();

            if( !$q = $this->_db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`,`email`,`country_code`,`newsletter`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)") ) { printf('error on prepare'); }
            if( !$q->bind_param('sssi', $data['name'], $data['email'], $country_code, $optin)) { printf('error on bind'); }
            if( !$q->execute() )  { printf('error on execute'); }

            printf('Insert error %s', $this->_db->error);

            if( $this->_db->affected_rows == 0 ) {
                // There was a problem with the insert  

                printf('Insert error %s', $this->_db->error);
            }

            $q->close();
    }
```

I also tried adding the boolean value as a string, but it still didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

The issue was that I was not providing all column values ( I want to update those later, as they are not available on the html form submit ).

I needed to assign a default value for those columns which will not be filled on the initial INSERT.

The error message however was not helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you set $optin to true/false instead of 1/0?

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !isset($data['name']) || !isset($data['email']) || !isset($data['newsletter']) )
    $optin = ( $data['newsletter'] === 'on' ) ? 1 : 0;
```

Basically if the criteria for this if are not true so you don't "enter" your if your $optin variable will be null/undefined.

If you want to avoid that there are 2 ways.

1) change the accepted value in your newsletter field in the db to accept null

2)

```
$optin=0;
if( !isset($data['name']) || !isset($data['email']) || !isset($data['newsletter']) ){
    if($data['newsletter'] === 'on' ){
        $optin=1;
    }
}

    $country_code = $this->Get_Country_Code();
```

Define your variable with the "negative" value you want to be set if your criteria are not matched and change it inside your if.